# how to position my BS-CS and stars to the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I want to fix the BS-CS and stars portion stick to the bottom of my container but i can't do that what should i do now
here is my bootstrap code.

```html
<div className="item1 col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 my-4"> {/* col-12 -> to display only 1 card in mobile of all col // col-md-6 -> display 2 cards in medium devices // col-lg-6 -> also display 2 cards in large devices // col-xl-4 -> display 3 cards in extra large devices */}
                <div className="row teacher_card">
                    {/* for teacher images */}
                    <div className="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 teacher_img">
                        <img src={props.teacher_img} className="img-fluid img_size" alt="Teacher pic" />
                    </div>
                    {/* Teacher Discription infprmation */}
                    <div className="col-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8 teacher_info">
                        <div className="teacher_name"> {/* pt-4 -> padding top 4px // pb-3 -> padding top 3px */}
                            <h1> {props.teacher_name} </h1>
                            <p> {props.teacher_info} </p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="teacher_edu_city ">
                            <div className="teacher_edu_city-in d-flex justify-content-between">
                                <h5> {props.teacher_edu} </h5>
                                <h5> {props.teacher_city} </h5>
                            </div>
                            <p>  </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to position your stars in bottom of your content, you can do with  position.

give a class to stars

then in css:

```
.teacher_info {       
    position: relative;        
}

.stars {   
  position: absolute;  
  left: 0;  
  bottom: 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Give `div.item1` Element `d-flex flex-column` classes if you are using bootstrap 4+, Or just add this styles to

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

Second, You can add `mt-auto` to `div.teacher_edu_city` , Or use this styles

```
margin-top: auto;
```

That's it.